Best way to export cloud watch metrics periodically (to S3 as csv)
I have the bones of the lambda function, to extract and convert the metric to csv.
But I have seen so many different options for scheduling it, SQS/Firehose/EventBridge.
It just needs to log periodically due to the 15mths max retention. Can I do this in cloud watch which would exclude the need for another service ? If not what is the most straight forward/cheapest method?
I haven’t tried anything since I don’t want to start before I have the best implementation method

FYI this question is off-topic, as there are no specifics - just some requirements and a request for recommendations. Also, there is no "best" implementation method, as there are always tradeoffs. Please check out [ask].

If you just need to run the Lambda function periodically, on a schedule, then scheduling it with an EventBridge cron schedule trigger is the correct way to do this. If you scheduled it through the AWS Lambda web UI, the UI would create an EventBridge cron trigger for you.
Or you could use EventBridge Scheduler which is a newer feature of EventBridge that has some additional features like retries and configurable delivery time windows.
Either of those EventBridge features have a huge free-tier that you will probably never go over.

SQS and Firehose would only be useful if you needed some external service to send events to your Lambda function, along with some sort of message for the Lambda function to process. If you were using one of those, then you would have to have some service pushing messages to SQS or Firehose on a schedule, and you would be back to the problem of figuring out how to schedule that.
